# Using verb continuous for living abroad for a period of time

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, present-tense, progressive-aspect

Suppose that a friend of mine is Thai and he usually lives in Thailand.  Now he is in Australia and he is going to live in Australia for only a few years.

Should I say “A friend of mine is living in Australia” rather than “A friend of mine lives in Australia”? Is that right?

Comment: You might be interested in our proposal for an [English language learners](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/41665/english-language-learners?referrer=9vM09OKxbaY8GxFV_g6lKw2) Q&A site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, I would say, "A friend of mine is living in Australia *for a year.*"

'*Lives in Australia*' implies a permanent (or at least as far as plans can be known) arrangement while '*is living in*' implies a more temporary situation. But as above, I would always qualify it with a time period.  Or you could say, "A friend of mine is currently living in Australia."

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible. The progressive emphasizes on the duration of living, while the simple present does not. I would use the progressive, but that doesn't mean the other is incorrect.